# How to conserve the highchart graph locally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using highchart library for creating charts.

Need to change the graph data on every period. so i can do this by following possibility

1. Render the chart on data changes
2. Update the data and redraw the graph on data changes
3. Store the graph data locally

Is there any option store the graph or graph's data locally except above option?

Ex: Save Whole DOM element.

Main goal is, I don't want render the graph again and again on data changes and trying to store the whole graph data not only data even including all the configuration

Comment: You can keep your data in local storage - read more about it on w3 web http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the issue, as well as your thoughts on solving it. You state both that you need to update the chart "on every period", but that you don't want to update the chart every time. Which of those two things are you trying to accomplish, and what about it are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Its Not Possible Or feasible to store the Graph Locally

**Disadvantages**

1. There Might Be changes in your Graph at runtime
2. High chart API works on Javascript and Jquery ,so It runs completly on browser ,It not creating any kind of load on machine ,unless It fires a background Query To Get Data and Then Load It.

Chances Are you can save the graph only in the case If you have static Data to be shown in Graph ,which you can store at your drive and load it later .

For Saving Graph You Can Either Give A PDf save option or Generate an Image or Pdf file for that Graph .
But That will Be of No use Instead It will create Load .